# What is a basis actually is and how it differs from primitive unit cell?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model

I have some questions about primitive unit cell and basis. These are:

1. Is the basis the smallest identical fragment of a crystal which repeats in a pattern throughout
   the crystal? Or can it be an identical fragment of any size which containing smaller identical
   fragments?
2. Can a basis be called the primitive unit cell of a space lattice?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Bravais lattices and you will find that there are only 14 types of crystal types (quasicrystals are different). There are only 14 different ways to choose nonequivalent basis vectors in 3-space, and using these basis vectors, only 4 different spacial lattice types can be generated. So in that way basis vectors are fundamental.

However to describe a crystal you can come up with your own lattice vectors, from looking at the positions of the atoms and describe the crystal. You can also come up with different ways to find a primitive vectors and and primitive unit cell. Primitive unit cells are defined as unit cells with the smallest volume for a given crystal. The requirements for the primitive unit cell is that it contains one lattice point and when repeated (translated along lattice points) it reproduces the whole crystal. You can also represent a crystal with a [conventional](https://msestudent.com/simple-hexagonal-unit-cell/) cell, that may have larger volume than the primitive cell.

[image: wurtzite crystal]

Answer (score 0):

> What is a basis actually is and how it differs from primitive unit cell?

A crystal can be described as a 3D repetition of simple building blocks. This building block contains a basis of atoms with a given set of spacing and angles that recur at every lattice point in the crystal. The block can also be described as a primitive unit cell of a given volume (typically parallelpiped) and the basis is the matter contained in the unit cell.

Comment: That means a primitive unit cell is region in space and basis is atoms contained in that space?

Answer (score 0):

The primitive unit cell is the smallest identical fragment of a crystal which repeats in a pattern throughout the crystal.

A basis is a minimal set of vectors that spans a vector space. There are many sets of basis vectors in any non-trivial vector space. For example, the usual basis for ordinary $3$ dimensional space, $\mathbb{R}^3$, is $\{(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0)\}$. These span $\mathbb{R}^3$ because any vector in it can be expressed as a linear combination of them. It is minimal because it has $3$ vectors, and no smaller set will work.

Perhaps you are thinking of lattice vectors, which are vectors along the edges  of a unit cell. These are examples of basis vectors.

Comment: That is not the basis op is talking about. It’s an unfortunate overuse of terminology, but a basis in crystallography is the set of atoms in a primitive unit cell in A crystal lattice. It’s not really related to the linear algebra notion of basis at all.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a cubic system, of atoms of an element A at all vertex. And inside each cube there is an atom of another element B. $\frac{1}{8}$ of each atom of A belongs to a given cube. So for each cube there is one atom of A and one atom of B. The chemical formula is AB.

In this case, the long range symmetry of system is cubic simple, but the unit cell is called 'with a basis'. That means: for each cubic unit cell there is a extra B atom placed at the center. The $3$ vectors defined by lines joining vertex atoms are not enough to generate all the lattice positions (B is out of the span of that vectors).

Now there is the lattice for the $\alpha$ iron. It is similar, except that the atom inside the cube is also of iron. The unit cell can be chosen as $4$ atoms: $3$ at vertex, and one at the center. The vectors defined that way can span all the lattice. So we have another Bravais lattice: body centered cubic, and not more simple cubic as before.